# IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration',

Tags: asp.net-web-api, botframework, bots, openid-connect

My bot is implemented using v3 bot builder, and its hosted in Azure web app(previously hosed on prem IIS Server). after migrating the bot to Azure web app, it stopped working and I could observe the below error form application insights. I have enabled proxy and also enabled TLS versions required in global.asax and enabled the corporate proxy as per the policy. but could not resolve the issues.

> Error refreshing OpenId configuration: System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond...

I have referred multiple links but could not really resolve it.

Comment: look like this issue is related to network connectivity, check proxy or nsg rules,etc .

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, it was failing because it needed default proxy settings need to be enabled. Just enabled the default proxy settings with org proxy And it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Bot Service will require all connections to be secured using Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.2. It doesn't support TLS 1.0 anymore.

https://blog.botframework.com/2018/11/06/announcement-azure-bot-service-enforcing-transport-layer-security-tls-1-2/

You may add something like this in startup code -

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```